# Rails: Creating a csv file in a rake task - can't access a classes database column_names

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I am struggling to create a simple rake task which will generate a csv dump of the database table "baselines".

```
task :send_report => :environment do
  path = "tmp/"
  filename = 'data_' + Date.today.to_s + '.csv'
   Baseline.all.each do
    CSV.open(path + filename, "wb") do |csv|
      csv << Baseline.column_names
      Baseline.all.each do |p|
        csv << p.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

I am getting the error

```
       undefined local variable or method `column_names' for main:Object
```

I am completely unclear why this is....Baseline.column_names will work in the console, in a view etc etc.

Any thought would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying `Baseline.column_names` in the first case, but just `column_names` on your `values_at` call. That defaults to the `main` context where no such method exists. It must be called against a model.

Make those two consistent, `Baseline` is required in both cases.

Comment: Thank! - that seems to work (it doesn't throw an error). The problem I am having now is that the file isn't appearing in the tmp directory in the public folder.

Comment: Why would it? You're asking for `tmp/` relative to the current directory, which is probably the Rails root. If you wanted it there: `path = Rails.root.join('public/tmp')`.

Comment: Many thanks. Marked as correct as both your comments together solved my issue